# GitHub/git - how to make only one branch (gp-pages) and delete other branches

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I have git repository with site, that is publish on GitHub pages (`gh-pages` branch).

Now I want to have only one branch `gh-pages` and delete all others (local and on server)

The answer that pops-up is [How do I delete a Git branch both locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-in-github) , however when doing

`git push origin --delete master`

remote: error: refusing to delete the current branch: refs/heads/master
To https://github.com/Nodeclipse/www.nodeclipse.com.git
 ! [remote rejected] master (deletion of the current branch prohibited)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Nodeclipse/www.nodeclipse
.com.git'

With Eclipse EGit I can delete in UI but it remains on server, and after `pull` comes back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to change the default branch in your remote repo to be something other than the `master` branch:

[image]

Comment: That was exactly the case